# How to change background with a dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi im not currently that great at JavaScript and i have ran into a problem. im making a website to show off what i can do and in the section where i will show layouts i want to have options so they can change the colours of the page to see what it looks like. Now i have done this using radio buttons and it works great but i want to put it into a a drop down to make it look better.

The code with radio buttons:

```
<form action="">
        <input onclick="change_color_body_blue()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Blue
        <input onclick="change_color_body_green()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Green
        <input onclick="change_color_body_red()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Red
        <input onclick="change_color_body_yellow()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Yellow
        <input onclick="change_color_body_orange()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Orange
        <input onclick="change_color_body_purple()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Purple
        <input onclick="change_color_body_brown()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Brown
        <input onclick="change_color_body_cream()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Cream
        <input onclick="change_color_body_pink()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Pink
        <input onclick="change_color_body_hotpink  ()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>HotPink
        <input onclick="change_color_body_black()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>Black
        <input onclick="change_color_body_white()" type="radio" name="Content_body_color"/>White
    </form>
```

Now for the code with the dropdown

```
        <form action="">
    <select>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_blue()" name="Content_body_color">Blue</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_green()" name="Content_body_color">Green</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_red()" name="Content_body_color">Red</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_yellow()" name="Content_body_color">Yellow</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_orange()" name="Content_body_color">Orange</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_purple()" name="Content_body_color">Purple</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_brown()" name="Content_body_color">Brown</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_cream()" name="Content_body_color">Cream</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_pink()" name="Content_body_color">Pink</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_hotpink  ()" name="Content_body_color">HotPink</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_black()" name="Content_body_color">Black</option>
        <option onchange="change_color_body_white()" name="Content_body_color">White</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

I have tried onchange onclick and onselect but none work i have also added one of the events to the select tag this works but it will only change to 1 colour as only 1 of my functions can be entered can anyone see a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <select onchange="javascript:changeColor(this);">
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Green</option>
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        <option>Purple</option>
        <option>Brown</option>
        <option>Cream</option>
        <option>Pink</option>
        <option>HotPink</option>
        <option>Black</option>
        <option>White</option>
    </select>
<script>
function changeColor(el) {
    var color = el.value;
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked!! may i ask though what el stands for and why the "this" needs to be in the "changeColor(this)" i just want to understand what im doing :D

Comment: ok (this) means the current object in use, it is a reference to the html DOM element. "el" it is only a parameter name who receives the "this" passed by the function.

Comment: Thanks i understand now and you have just saved me alot of coding i spent all day yesterday doing the radio buttons for the body divs borders and so on but this way is so much quicker and eiser :D